# how to get two lists in drools when section

Tags: java, collections, drools

I have two lists in the drools session: List and List, where the Address and ProviderAddress are the business objects.

```
...
kSession.insert(listOfAddresses);
kSession.insert(listOfProviderAddresses);
kSession.fireAllRules();
...
```

What should I do from the left side to get the lists from the session, and how to avoid possible double executed rule?

when

```
 $addresses : ...
 $providerAddresses: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to use container classes such as List as facts.

1. Insert the list elements. In case you do need one or both lists, you can always use accumulate or collect.
2. Wrap the lists into classes so you can distinguish them.